# Blender- python

Tags: python, blender

How do I point Blender to the version of python I have installed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mark, your version of Blender should be compiled with a specific version of Python interfaced to it -- and THAT is the version of Python you need to install on your machine. The same issue surfaced back when Python 2.5 was reasonably new and Blender was still distributed with 2.4 compiled;

I suspect you maybe running into exactly the same issue.
What message of the form "Compiled with Python 2.x" does your Blender give at the start?

That should be your clue for what Python to install (unless you want to recompile Blender from source to support your favorite version of Python, of course!)

Comment: Thanx Alex,
It was easier to get the corresponding version of python (2.5).

Answer (score 5):

Blender 2.5x now comes bundled with its own python, this is un-modified, only included to so users don't have to match their system versions of python.

If you remove this python/ directory blender will look for python on the system, matching the version it was compiled with. (3.2, 3.3 etc, minor point releases are all inter compatible).

If you want to point to a non-standard python path you can set PYTHONHOME environment variable - python documents how this works (nothing specific to blender).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I was setting my PATH environment variable so that Blender would find the most appropriate version of Python first.

Comment: and how to do that? i'm using python 2.6 so somehow i have to point blender at that. i'm an ignoramus with no idea about python

Comment: If you're running in a Windows environment you can modify your PATH variable in System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables. You can get to System Properties by right-clicking My Computer and selecting Properties or by going to "System" in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open your Blender application;

2.Go to Widow screen layout for **Scripting** (from top of window Blender)

3.Under **Console** for python scripting will see your python version, see my output:

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.5.1 (default, Feb 17 2016, 17:09:19) [MSC v.1800 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>>
```